# Call method of lazy generic type with reflection in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.reflection

I want to call *close* method of _baseInfoService with reflection if *IsValueCreated*. how can I do it with reflection?

```
public static partial class ServiceFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>> _baseInfoService = 
        new Lazy<ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>>(CreateWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>);

    public static IBaseInfoWcfService BaseInfoService => _baseInfoService.Value.Instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ServiceWrapper<T>
{
    public T Instance { get; private set; }

    public ServiceWrapper(T instance) {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    public void Close() {

    }
}

public interface IBaseInfoWcfService
{

}

public class BaseInfoWcfServiceImpl : IBaseInfoWcfService
{
    public BaseInfoWcfServiceImpl() {

    }
}

public static partial class ServiceFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>> _baseInfoService =
        new Lazy<ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>>(CreateWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>);

    public static IBaseInfoWcfService BaseInfoService => _baseInfoService.Value.Instance;

    private static ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService> CreateWrapper<T>() where T : IBaseInfoWcfService {
        return new ServiceWrapper<IBaseInfoWcfService>(new BaseInfoWcfServiceImpl());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var baseInfoService = typeof(ServiceFactory).GetField("_baseInfoService", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var instance = baseInfoService.GetValue(null);
    var isValueCreated = (bool)instance.GetType().GetProperty("IsValueCreated").GetValue(instance);

    if (isValueCreated) {
        var value = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(instance);
        var close = (Action)value.GetType().GetMethod("Close").CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), value);

        close();
    }
}
```